# Javascript prototypical inheritence with object.create and call gives not function error

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am moving my head around JavaScript prototypical Inheritance. I am taking the help of following link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

I have a person object:

```
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.interests = interests;
};
```

I have inherited it to teacher object:

```
function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interests, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interests);

  this.subject = subject;
}
```

Now, I defined a function on Person prototype:

```
Person.prototype.sayHello = function (){
   console.log("hello");
}
```

Now, I want to call it via teacher:

```
var teacher = new Teacher("khan","khan",1,"mile","hockey","english");
teacher.prototype.sayHello();
```

It gives:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sayHello' of undefined
>       at :1:19

Calling it directly yields the same result:

```
teacher.sayHello();
```

Let me make constructor right:

```
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);

teacher.sayHello();
```

> VM203:1 Uncaught TypeError: teacher.sayHello is not a function
>           at :1:9

Same result. What am I missing?

Comment: It works, you just have to do it in the right order. Specifically, assigning to `Teacher.prototype` after already having created the `new Teacher` will not change the existing `teacher`'s prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just calling the `Person` function and pass to him the context which uses that to initialize the properties. You call it like if you call another function inside it. `Person` is not in the prototype chain of the `Teacher`. You also need to explicitly add it into the chain.

```js
function Person(first, last, age, gender, interests) {
  this.name = {
    first,
    last
  };
  this.age = age;
  this.gender = gender;
  this.interests = interests;
};

function Teacher(first, last, age, gender, interests, subject) {
  Person.call(this, first, last, age, gender, interests);

  this.subject = subject;
}

// Set the prototype an empty object which prototype is the Person.prototype
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
// Preserve the constructor
Teacher.constructor = Teacher;

Person.prototype.sayHello = function (){
   console.log("hello");
}

var teacher = new Teacher("khan","khan",1,"mile","hockey","english");
teacher.sayHello();
```

Comment: I am a little bit confused with `// Set the prototype an empty object which prototype is the Person.prototype`. What does it do, if it doesn't point to Parent constructor?

Comment: `Teacher.prototype` -> `(empty object).prototype` -> `Person.prototype`. `Teacher.prototype` will be changed and the constructor will be lost. So I set it again. You have an intermediate object, so when you will add something into `Teacher.prototype`, it will  affect `(empty object)`, not `Person.prototype`

Comment: @SurenSrapyan There is no intermediate object anywhere? The object created by `Object.create` *is* `Teacher.prototype` (after the assignment), and it does directly inherit from `Person.prototype`.

Comment: Oh Sorry. I imagine the chain (arrows) and automatically make mistake. Thanks